# How can I track who clicked what in my member area?

Tags: user-meta, user-registration

I have a protected member area where registered members (= logged in with a Wordpress user account) can click to view videos and click to download PDF files. I want to know which user clicked what link, and how many times. Thanks!

Comment: Google Analytics utilizing User ID or Client ID. But read about GDPR compliance first.

Comment: You can use Activity log plugin since all your users are logged in